# Concentration of the norm (sub-gaussianity)

Tags: probability-theory, concentration-of-measure

I'm trying to solve the following problem (exercise 3.1.4 of [these notes](https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf))

> Suppose $X = (X_1, \dots, X_n) \in \mathbf{R}^n$ is a random vector with independent, sub-gaussian coordinates $X_i$, each of which satisfy $\mathbf{E} X_i^2 = 1$. Show that: 
>   $$
> \sqrt{n} - CK^2 \leq \mathbf{E}\|X\|_2 \leq \sqrt{n} + CK^2.
> $$
>   Can $CK^2$ be replaced by $o(1)$, a quantity that vanishes as $n \to \infty$?

**Notation:** $\|\cdot\|_{\psi_2}$ refers to the sub-gaussian norm.

**What I've tried:**

The first statement is equivalent to showing that $|\mathbf{E} \|X\|_2 - \sqrt{n}| \leq CK^2$. From Theorem 3.1.1 of the notes above, I know that $\|\|X\|_2 - \sqrt{n}\|_{\psi_2} \leq CK^2$. Thus, it would suffice to establish that
$$
|\mathbf{E} \|X\|_2 - \sqrt{n}| \leq \|\|X\|_2 - \sqrt{n}\|_{\psi_2}
$$
By Jensen's inequality, 
$$
|\mathbf{E} \|X\|_2 - \sqrt{n}| \leq \mathbf{E} |\|X\|_2 - \sqrt{n}| =  \|\|X\|_2 - \sqrt{n}\|_{L_1}.
$$
But by equation 2.15 (of the same notes):
$$
|\mathbf{E} \|X\|_2 - \sqrt{n}| \leq \|\|X\|_2 - \sqrt{n}\|_{L_1}
\leq C' \|\|X\|_2 - \sqrt{n}\|_{\psi_2} \leq C' \cdot CK^2.
$$

**Question:** I'm not sure if this the tightest way to solve the first part of the problem. As you can see, I have to incur another absolute constant. Also, any help with the statement regarding whether $CK^2$ can be $o(1)$ would be appreciated. I have no idea.

Comment: Somewhat related, but I love the coffee cups as an indication of difficulty.

Comment: True. Apparently this is supposed to be a some what hard problem. @Dfrtbx

Comment: If anyone else is confused like I was, $\|\cdot\|_{\psi_2}$ refers to the *sub-gaussian norm* and is defined in def. 2.5.6.

Comment: I cannot seem to find equation 2.1.5.

Comment: @Dfrtbx It is on the top of page 28. It says that for subgaussian random variable $U$, $\|U\|_{L_p} \leq C\|U\|_{\psi_2}\sqrt{p}$. I've also updated the text of my question to clarify the notation.

Comment: Oh, that is equation 2.15, not equation 2.1.5, haha

Comment: Yes my bad, @Dfrtbx, my sincerest apologies! I'll update the text of the problem accordingly.

Comment: Unfortunately I seem to be a little out of my depth, but I'm glad that I could help you clean up the question a tad. If this remains unanswered I will revisit it later.

Answer (score 2):

Using $e^x \geq 1+x$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}exp\left (\frac{(\|X\|_2-\sqrt{n})^2}{(\mathbb{E}\|X\|_2-\sqrt{n})^2}\right ) & \geq 1+\mathbb{E}\frac{(\|X\|_2-\sqrt{n})^2}{(\mathbb{E}\|X\|_2-\sqrt{n})^2} \\
& = 1+\frac{\mathbb{E}\|X\|_2^2-2\sqrt{n}\mathbb{E}\|X\|_2+n}{(\mathbb{E}\|X\|_2)^2-2\sqrt{n}\mathbb{E}\|X\|_2+n} \\
&\geq 2
\end{align*}
hence 
$$
|\mathbb{E}\|X\|_2-\sqrt{n}| \leq \|\|X\|_2-\sqrt{n}\|_{\psi_2}\leq CK^2
$$

[other solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3537390/show-the-variance-here-is-bounded-using-the-concentration-of-norm-theorem)

[replace $CK^2$ with $o(1)$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325862/expectation-of-the-norm-of-a-random-vector)

Comment: I agree with everything until the "hence" part. Can you spell out the remaining details?

Comment: @DrewBrady Recall the definition of $ \| X \| _{\psi_2} $ that $\mathbb{E} \exp (X^2/\| X \| _{\psi_2} ^2) \leq 2$. It is then less than or equal to the LHS of the second line. So we got something like $\mathbb{E} \exp (X^2/a^2) \leq \mathbb{E} \exp (X^2/b^2)$. Hence, $b^2 \leq a^2$. The remaining part is taking square root on both sides.