# show the variance here is bounded using the concentration of norm theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, probability-distributions, upper-lower-bounds

Let $X\in{}\mathbb{R}^N$, with independent sub-gaussian coordinates s.t. $E[X_i^2]=1, E[X_i]=0$.

W.T.S:

$\text{Var}(\|X\|_2)\le{C'K^4}$ with $C'>0$ and $K:=\max_{1\le{i\le{N}}}{\|X_i\|_{\psi^2}}$,

I don't know where to start, ive tried using various properties of sub-gaussian r.v. with no luck, any hints?

***The concentration of the norm theorem:***

Let $X\in{}\mathbb{R}^N$, with independent sub-gaussian coordinates s.t. $E[X_i^2]=1$.
$$\|\|X\|_2-\sqrt{n}\|_{\Psi^2}\le{CK^2},\space{}C>0,\space{}K:=\max_{1\le{i\le{N}}}{\|X_i\|_{\psi^2}}$$

$$$$
$$$$

$$$$

P.S. I have shown the fact that:

$$\sqrt{n}-CK^2\le{}\mathbb{E}[\|X\|_2]\le{}\sqrt{n}+CK^2$$

I essentially used the theorem, found a lower bound of the subgaussian norm of $\|X\|_2-\sqrt{n}$ with the Lp norm, set p to 1. and used Jensens inequality since $f(x)=|x|$ is a convex function.

I am using the following book and believe the question is similar to ex3.1.4:
 https://www.math.uci.edu/~rvershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf

Comment: The fact above with the assumptions provided is the concentration of the norm theorem, I will label it accordingly.

Comment: I will provide a sketch of the proof I have done, also I am using the text: 'High-Dimensional Probability: An Introduction with Applications in Data Science
Book by Roman Vershynin'

Comment: Well actually, its from my lecture notes which are based on the book> I found it in the book as Exercise 3.1.4, but it's not quite the same. In the book we want to show that the variance is equal to $O(1)$.

Comment: Those are the notes I am using yes.

Comment: Presumably $\Psi$ and $||\cdot||_{\Psi^2}$ mean something.

Comment: @Michael yes, they refer to the sub-gaussian norm.

Comment: "found a lower bound of the subgaussian norm using the $L^p$ norm" : can you elaborate here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with $\text{Var}\|X\|_2 = \operatorname{E}(\|X\|_2 - \operatorname{E}\|X\|_2)^2 \leq \operatorname{E}(\|X\|_2 - \sqrt{n})^2$ because the mean $\text{E}\|X\|_2$ minimizes the mean squared error. It is used for a similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3114692/642015).

Further, by using the inequality for the $L_1$ norm $|\|X\|_2 - \sqrt{n}| \leq CK^2$ you obtained we have the upper bound as follows, $$\text{Var}\|X\|_2 \leq \text{E}(\|X\|_2 - \sqrt{n})^2 \leq C^2K^4 .$$

Answer (score 0):

You can expand the definition of variance and use the mean linear property:
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \text{Var}(\|X\|_{2}) &= \mathbb{E}(\|X\|_{2} - \mathbb{E}\|X\|_{2} )^{2} \\
    &= \mathbb{E}\|X\|_{2}^{2} - 2(\mathbb{E}\|X\|_{2})^{2} + (\mathbb{E}\|X\|_{2})^{2} \\
    &= \mathbb{E}\|X\|_{2}^{2} - (\mathbb{E}\|X\|_{2})^{2} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Since $\mathbb{E}X_{i}^{2} = 1$, $\mathbb{E}\|X\|_{2}^{2} = n$ and you can bound the second term using what you already have
$$
\begin{aligned}
    \text{Var}(\|X\|_{2}) &= \mathbb{E}\|X\|_{2}^{2} - (\mathbb{E}\|X\|_{2})^{2} \\
    &\leq n - (\sqrt{n} + CK^{2})^{2} \\
    &= -2\sqrt{n}CK^{2} + C^{2}K^{4} \\
    &\leq C^{2}K^{4}
\end{aligned}
$$